# How to set the default value for select?

Tags: angular, forms, select

I have a form that consists of several fields (select) and so far it is the user who selects the values in the fields from the list.

However, I would like a value to be automatically set in one field (the value is already on another component and would be taken from it).
How would I handle such a case with an if or some special component? Because I don't have too much idea how to do it.

So, for example, a user previously enters that they are from Germany, then the country would automatically be marked as Germany in a field on the form. The user wouldn't have to enter it again, because they had already entered it before.

This is what select looks like so far:

This can be done in a total of two ways we can set the select automatically without being able to select another country from the list (the country is set by default and the list is not available), or we can set the country, but when you change it, you can still select other countries from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to your formControl

Ex:

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
   ...

   this.form.get('country').setValue(yourDefaultValue);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

This should I pass as an attribute to `formControlName` or do I need to create a separate `FormControl` class?

Comment: nono, your ng-select has a formControlName. Its the same name that appears in this line this.form.get('country').setValue(yourDefaultValue);